# Play media from from zip file without unzipping

Tags: android, zip, android-mediaplayer

I know there are already a few questions like this on SO, but they relate to extracting the file before playing it.

In the Android docs [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) it explains that you can play files directly from a .zip file without extracting it.

> Tip: If you're packaging media files into a ZIP, you can use media
>   playback calls on the files with offset and length controls (such as
>   [MediaPlayer.setDataSource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28java.io.FileDescriptor,%20long,%20long%29) and SoundPool.load()) without the need to
>   unpack your ZIP. In order for this to work, you must not perform
>   additional compression on the media files when creating the ZIP
>   packages. For example, when using the zip tool, you should use the -n
>   option to specify the file suffixes that should not be compressed:
>
> zip -n .mp4;.ogg main_expansion media_files

I've made an (uncompressed) zip package, but I cannot figure out how to get from a `ZipEntry` to a `FileDescriptor`, and they don't explain any further. How do I get a `FileDescriptor` without unpacking the zip file?

Comment: The [zip file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29) uses a fairly simple internal file structure. The header points to the data, so you just need to look for the file header, then use the `Relative offset of local file header` and `Compressed size` to find the start of the data and its length. You should also at least check the `Compression method` to be sure the file is uncompressed, and as long as it is not compressed, use the data, otherwise uncompress the data first, then use it.

Comment: The compression method is `store` using 7zip, and the .zip file's size is equal to the sum of the unzipped files so I think I've zipped them correctly. Other than that, I have no idea what you're talking about :P

Comment: I ran into the same kind of problem not long ago, but haven't had any luck making it work. You can check these questions for more details:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863731/open-a-file-from-archive-without-temporary-extraction
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920429/anyone-have-mediaplayer-working-with-parcelfiledescriptor-and-createpipe

Answer (score 4):

You can use **The APK Expansion Zip Library** to do that even if you do not use APK Expansions in your app.

Follow this documentation to get the library: [Using the APK Expansion Zip Library](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#ZipLib)

Zip your sound files **without** compression using your favorite zip tool.

Use this code to load the music:

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = new ZipResourceFile("myZipFile.zip");
AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("myMusic.mp3");
try {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle exception
}
```

Comment: I've since moved on to other methods, but if anyone can confirm this I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work f the zip file is compressed.

Comment: at what folder myZipFile.zip should be located?

Answer (score 3):

There aren't many recent solutions for this issue, so I was stuck on this, too – until I created a new instance of MediaPlayer in the function where I was trying to read the zip file. Suddenly playback started without problems. Now, instead, I'm passing my (global) MediaPlayer to the function like this: (Kotlin)

```
private fun preparePlayer(mp: MediaPlayer, position: Int) {

    // Path of shared storage
    val root: File = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    Log.i("ROOT", root.toString())

    // path of the zip file
    val zipFilePath = File(root.absolutePath+"/Android/obb/MY_PACKAGE_NAME/MY_ZIP_FILE.zip")

    // Is zip file recognized?
    val zipFileExists = zipFilePath.exists()
    Log.i("Does zip file exist?", zipFileExists.toString())

    // Define the zip file as ZipResourceFile
    val expansionFile = ZipResourceFile(zipFilePath.absolutePath)

    // Your media in the zip file
    val afd = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("track_01.mp3")

    // val mp = MediaPlayer()   // not necessary if you pass it as a function parameter
    mp.setDataSource(afd.fileDescriptor, afd.startOffset, afd.length)
    mp.prepare()
    mp.start()   // Music should start playing automatically
```

Maybe this can help someone else. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    ZipFile zf= new ZipFile(filename);
    ZipEntry ze = zip.getEntry(fileName);
    if (ze!= null) {
        InputStream in = zf.getInputStream(ze);
        File f = File.createTempFile("_AUDIO_", ".wav");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
        // play f
    }
} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

[possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900249/can-android-mediaplayer-play-audio-in-a-zipped-file)

Comment: Thank you for your example, but I already knew how to create temp files.. The question was about accessing the files without unzipping them. Looks like it isn't possible without major hax, though.

Comment: Oh, then may be I am misunderstood. As i never find anything like playing a file without unzipping it or without using temp files. I have a doubt whether you can find a method. If there is any it will be great if you share.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a media file from a zip without unzipping you have to add also start offset and length to `setDataSource`.

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = new ZipResourceFile("myZipFile.zip");
AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("myMusic.mp3");
try {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                              assetFileDescriptor.getStartOffset(),
                              assetFileDescriptor.getLength());
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom MediaDataSource like this:

```
public class ZipMediaDataSource extends MediaDataSource {

    private InputStream inputStream;

    public ZipMediaDataSource(ZipFile file, ZipEntry zipEntry) throws IOException {
        inputStream = file.getInputStream(zipEntry);
    }

    @Override
    public int readAt(long position, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size) throws IOException {
        return inputStream.read(buffer, offset, size);
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize() throws IOException {
        return inputStream.available();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
            inputStream = null;
        }
    }
}
```

usage is:

```
ZipMediaDataSource zipMediaDataSource = new ZipMediaDataSource(zipFile, zipEntry);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(zipMediaDataSource);
```